# ImportError only for crontab job?

Tags: python, import, cron, jira

So I wrote a nifty automation script that does some of my work for me via the jira module + handy dandy logic.  It runs perfectly from the command line via:

```
me@local] ~/Documents/auto_updater > python /Users/me/Documents/auto_updater/jira_updater.py 
Missing info starting
  checking out:  ES-20157
    No array outage
    Already has sev1_missing_outage label.
***snip***
```

It also works just fine ran with fullpath without the python call:

```
me@local] ~/Documents/auto_updater > /Users/me/Documents/auto_updater/jira_updater.py 
Missing info starting
  checking out:  ES-20157
    No array outage
    Already has sev1_missing_outage label.
```

Now - assuming that it working means life is good, I decided to set it up on a crontab for 30 min periods, and I'm getting spam failures every time where it can't seem to find the jira module:

```
From me@me-mbp  Mon Oct 17 19:30:04 2016
Return-Path: <me@me-mbp>
X-Original-To: me
Delivered-To: me@me-mbp
Received: by me-mbp (Postfix, from userid 502)
    id 514D0203328A; Mon, 17 Oct 2016 19:30:00 -0600 (MDT)
From: me@me-mbp (Cron Daemon)
To: me@me-mbp
Subject: Cron <me@local> python /Users/me/Documents/auto_updater/jira_updater.py >> /Users/me/Documents/auto_updater/updated_log.txt
X-Cron-Env: <SHELL=/bin/sh>
X-Cron-Env: <PATH=/usr/bin:/bin>
X-Cron-Env: <LOGNAME=me>
X-Cron-Env: <USER=me>
X-Cron-Env: <HOME=/Users/me>
Message-Id: <20161018013004.514D0203328A@micheal.taylor-mbp>
Date: Mon, 17 Oct 2016 19:30:00 -0600 (MDT)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/me/Documents/auto_updater/jira_updater.py", line 3, in <module>
    from jira.client import JIRA
ImportError: No module named jira.client
```

Originally I had problems with the #!/usr/bin/python path, so I switched it to #!/usr/bin/env python:

```
[me@local] ~/Documents/auto_updater > head jira_updater.py 
#!/usr/bin/env python

from jira.client import JIRA
import random

# Here's some responses that we can randomize from so it doesn't feel quite so botty.
FIRST_RESPONSES = ['- Do you need help moving this forward?',
                  '- Can I help you get traction on this?',
```

I've seen some workarounds that state that I just need my cronjob to run with my pythonpath explicitely declared, but that seems like a shoddy workaround, and I've set up a server to run this for me, so I'd prefer to solve it by making things work properly - but what I can't figure out is why the cronjob run command can't seem to find the module, but I can as root run it with the same syntax as specified in the crontab.  I've verified this by manually running the same commant specified in the crontab:

```
me@local] ~/Documents/auto_updater > crontab -l
*/30 * * * * python /Users/me/Documents/auto_updater/jira_updater.py >> /Users/me/Documents/auto_updater/updated_log.txt
```

Anyone have any insight into why cronjob can't find the module, or is specifying the pythonpath manually really the only "fix"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

probably explicitly append the lib path for jira in jira_updater.py should do.

```
# added code below before import jira
# append path where jira lib located, for example in /usr/bin/lib
import sys
sys.path.append('/usr/bin/lib')

# if yout don't know where jira located, use code below to get jira path first
# then put the path found into code sys.path.append above
import imp;imp.find_module('jira')
```

Comment: That worked perfectly - it didn't like my pythonpath either, so thanks a ton!